# Token sharing and renewal in load balanced microservices architecture

Tags: microservices, load-balancing

How does the CD microservices OAuth/token mechanism work in a load balanced setup, more specifically, if all the microservices are load balanced (individual microservices are members of a group (1 LB group for all the Discovery Services, etc.), not entire sets)?

Is the token issued by Token Service from group A valid for Content Service D, etc. What about the token expiration/renewal, I would expect that to be handled seemlesly as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - Yes - It will work as long as it uses the same credentials and settings in both groups, token expiration/renewal it will work as expected with the help of Refresh tokens, **Refresh tokens** used to get a new access token, a client may use a refresh token to get a new access token issued by the authentication server. Common use cases include getting new access tokens after old ones have expired.

Refer to [Content Delivery OAuth authentication framework](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-81F2D60E-F9A6-4411-A047-B4A09F8733BC)

I did simulate this in 2 groups and tested and it's working fine as expected.

**Note:**

All the microservices both group nodes timezone settings should be identical.

I hope it helps